# Remove Optional("string") in Swift 2

Tags: nsstring, swift2

I have a problem for concatenate different String in one String. The code works, but I have a word that is inserted between each of my Strings. Thank you in advance for your response.

```
let locality = String(self.locality)
let postalCode = String(self.postalCode)
let administrativeArea = String(self.administrativeArea)
let country = String(self.country)

let addressFull = locality + ", " + postalCode + " " + administrativeArea + ", " + country
print(addressFull)
```

Output

```
Optional("..."), Optional("...") Optional("..."), Optional("...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.locality` and your other properties are Optional strings, so you have to safely unwrap them before using them.

Example with `if let`:

```
if let locality = String(self.locality), let postalCode = String(self.postalCode), let administrativeArea = String(self.administrativeArea), let country = String(self.country) {
    let addressFull = locality + ", " + postalCode + " " + administrativeArea + ", " + country
    print(addressFull)
}
```

You should study the documentation about [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309), it's a very important concept in Swift.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's wrong. It's my fault, I don't explain very well and I have not shown all my code.

Comment: What is the type of `self.locality`, is it not an Optional string? What does `print(self.locality)` say? And `self.postalCode` is probably an Optional Int. When you create strings with `String(Optional(...))` the result is also an Optional. // If I'm wrong, then please unaccept my answer so I can delete it - or provide more info in your question so I can try answering more accurately. But having the answer accepted + downvoted is very weird. :) Thank you.